# My service worker notification dialog is not showing when there is update

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

I setup my service worker to show update notification to the user after update. But the notification dialog is not showing up. What I am doing wrong?

**registerValidSW function in serviceWorker.js**

```
function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register(swUrl)
        .then(registration => {
            registration.update();

            setInterval(() => {
              registration.update();
              console.debug("Checked for update...");
            }, (1000 * 60) * 30);

            registration.onupdatefound = () => {
                const installingWorker = registration.installing;
                if (installingWorker == null) {
                    return;
                }
                installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
                    if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
                        if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {

                            console.log(
                                'New content is available and will be used when all ' +
                                    'tabs for this page are closed.'
                            );

                            <ReleaseDialog />


                            if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                                config.onUpdate(registration);
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

                            if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                                config.onSuccess(registration);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
        });
        
        let refreshing = false;

        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', () => {
            if (refreshing) {
                return;
            }
    
            refreshing = true;
            console.log("controller change")
            window.location.reload();
        });
}
```

**index.js**

```
serviceWorker.register({
    onUpdate: async function (registration) {
        const waitingServiceWorker = registration.waiting
        const bc = new BroadcastChannel('app-update');
            bc.postMessage('App has updated.');
    }
});
```

**dialog component**:

```
class ReleaseDialog extends React.Component {
    state = {
        open: false,
    };

    componentWillMount = () => {
        if (typeof BroadcastChannel !== 'undefined') {
            const updateChannel = new BroadcastChannel('app-update');
            updateChannel.addEventListener('message', event => {
                this.setState({open: true})
            });
        }
    }

    handleAccept = async () => {
        try {
            if (navigator && navigator.serviceWorker) {
                const waitingServiceWorker = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready

                if (waitingServiceWorker.waiting) {
                    waitingServiceWorker.waiting.postMessage({type: "SKIP_WAITING"});
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }
    }

    handleClose = () => {
        this.setState({open: false});
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Dialog
                    open={this.state.open}
                    onClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                    <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">New Version is Available!</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogActions>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleClose} color="default">
                            Cancel
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={this.handleAccept} color="primary" autoFocus={true}>
                            UPDATE
                        </Button>
                    </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
            </div>

        )
    }
}
 
export default ReleaseDialog;
```

**service-worker.js**

```
self.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  if (e.data && e.data.type === 'SKIP_WAITING') {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

Please note that I am using workbox, PWA with CRA. To force update I use to change the name of my cache with numbers. But when I load the page I am not getting the notification dialog to force the service worker to activate the new one.